# How can i remove a title screen element with fabric in Minecraft 1.18.1

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I am currently able to add elements to the title screen:

```
public abstract class MCEMixin extends Screen {

    protected MCEMixin(Text title) {
        super(title);
    }

    @Inject(at = @At("RETURN"), method = "initWidgetsNormal")
    private void addCustomButton(int y, int spacingY, CallbackInfo cI) {
        this.addDrawableChild(new ButtonWidget(this.width / 2 - 100, y, 200, 20, Text.of("MCEssentials | Singleplayer"), (button) -> {
            MinecraftClient.getInstance().setScreen(new SelectWorldScreen(this));
        }));
    }
}
```

I want to replace the singleplayer button with mine tho and I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use `ci.cancel()` (requires you to include `CallbackInfo` ci in your injected method) and copy/paste the fabric mc source to the function but just change the `Singleplayer` button.

Comment: not possible: org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.injection.callback.CancellationException: The call initWidgetsNormal is not cancellable.